# Protractor file upload using sendKeys has blank file type

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, upload, protractor

I am writing a protractor e2e test to test the behaviour of my file input when it receives a file. The code below works fine.

```
var fileToUpload = '../../../../Test/Resources/test.csv',
    absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

My issue is I have front-end validation on the file, to make sure its `type` is csv.

Using the same resource file, the input receives this data when uploading the file manually in the browser:

```
{
    "lastModified":1468332623909,
    "lastModifiedDate":"Tue Jul 12 2016 10:10:23 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "name":"test.csv",
    "size":270,
    "type":"text/csv",
    "webkitRelativePath":""
}
```

But from the test I get:

```
{
    "lastModified":1468332623909,
    "lastModifiedDate":"Tue Jul 12 2016 10:10:23 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "name":"test.csv",
    "size":270,
    "type":"",
    "webkitRelativePath":""
}
```

Is there a way to have the file type specified using protractor?

Comment: Does this button do anything in this json object when the file is uploaded? Take a look at the request when running from tests. If your app has a javascript to validade the object type, you will problably need to invoke the javascript function after uploading the file.

Comment: The button I use is just to browse for a file. The behaviour is invoked when the element is changed: 
`<input type="file" style="display:none" id="inputFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().loadFile(event)"/>`

Comment: Try firing the function mannuall. EG: `browser.executeScript("angular.element(this).scope().loadFile(event)")`

Comment: The `loadFile(event)` function is called, so that's not the problem. The problem is the data that the `loadFile` function receives. the `event` that is sent to `loadFile(event)` through the test is different than what is sent through doing it manually on the browser.

Comment: Just for debugging: set the full path to the csv and use this var in the sendKeys. E.g. `var fileToUpload = 'C:\\Test\\Resources\\test.csv';    
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(fileToUpload);`

Comment: The test is getting the correct file path. I tried what you said, with this code: `var fileToUpload = '/home/justin/test.csv';
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(fileToUpload);` 

But the result is the same.

Comment: Getting the same error with .zip, .doc and .xls files too. The file type is correctly getting populated for image and PDF files!!